# Remove minimum value from Array, but if duplicate remove only once

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following function which is supposed to remove the smallest value from an array, but if this is a duplicate it will just remove the first one and leave the others.

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var array2 = [5, 3, 2, 1, 4];
var array3 = [2, 2, 1, 2, 1];

function removeSmallest(numbers) {
  return numbers.filter(function(elem, pos, self) {
    if(elem == Math.min.apply(null, numbers) && pos == self.indexOf(elem)) {
      // Remove element from Array
      console.log(elem, pos);
      numbers.splice(pos, 1);
    };
    return numbers;
  });
};
```

Via `console.log(elem, pos)` I understand that I have correctly identified the smallest and first element in the array, but when I try to remove it through `splice()`, I end up getting the following result for the arrays:

```
array1 = [1, 3, 4, 5]; // But I expected [2, 3, 4, 5]
array2 = [5, 3, 2, 1]; // But I expected [5, 3, 2, 4]
array3 = [2, 2, 1, 1]; // But I expected [2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Do you know what is the issue with my code? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: `numbers=numbers.slice(pos,1)` - Use slice and store it

Comment: Not working, I still get the same result. Or can you show me a `fiddle` with the correct result? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function removeSmallest(numbers) {
    const smallest = Math.min.apply(null, numbers);
    const pos = numbers.indexOf(smallest);
    return numbers.slice(0, pos).concat(numbers.slice(pos + 1));
};
```

You shouldn't use `filter()` the way you do. It's also a good practice that a function should return a new array rather than modifying the existing one and you definitely shouldn't modify an array while iterating over it.

Comment: Thanks man! It worked :) But to complete your question, why am I using `filter()` in the wrong way?

Comment: `filter()` iterates over the array and invokes your predicate function with the current item. Your predicate function is supposed to return `true` or `false`. If `false`, the item is removed from the array. You're returning the array itself, which is "truthy" so nothing is ever removed from the array. In practice, you're just replicating the functionality of `forEach()`. More importantly though, you're splicing the array during an iteration. In this case, that causes the loop to miss iterating over one item.

Comment: If you were to use `filter()` to solve this, here's how you would do it: `return numbers.filter(function(elem, pos, self) { return elem !== Math.min.apply(null, numbers) || pos !== self.indexOf(elem); });` So in other words, the splice isn't just dangerous, it also needlessly bloats the code =)

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeSmallest(arr){
var temp=arr.slice(),smallElement=null;
temp.sort(sortReverse);
smallElement=temp[temp.length-1];
var position=arr.indexOf(smallElement);
arr.splice(pos,1);
console.log(arr);
}

function sortReverse (a,b){
if(a<b){return 1}
else if(a>b){return -1;}
else{return 0;}
}

var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
removeSmallest(array1);
```